How to efficiently look for a substring in a pandas df column
I have a large pandas df.
I'd need to loop through a specific column and look for a substring in each row.
For example, I'd have to find the row with source_id containing the substring '136704'.
This is my code
for row_num, row_data in my_df.iterrows():
    source_id = str(row_data['source_id'])
    if (source_id.contains('136704')):
        print(row_num, source_id)

where row_data['source_id'] are int numbers, for example
row_data['source_id'] = [5254261818006768512, 4688972310002481024, 5864639514713019392, 5853820767014992128, 5423800601092727168]. 

I get the following error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Thank you for any help you could provide

Please provide a [mre] of your input my_df and the matching expected output. You should not use iterrows, a simple out = my_df[my_df['source_id'].astype(str).str.contains('136704')] should be enough to filter your rows.

That said, to fix your loop approach, replace if source_id.contains('136704'): by if '136704' in source_id:.

@mozway: that's it! Thank you
